# How to split string of dates and convert into UTC dates using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have comma separated string containing date and want to convert it in UTC.

I wrote this code:

```
daterange1.Select(t => t.Split(',').Select(r => r.Replace(r, TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Parse(r), selectedTimeZone).ToString())));
```

but it just convert first element and not all the elements.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

```
daterange = "2016-02-15 17:30:00,2016-02-15 18:00:00;2016-02-16 17:30:00,2016-02-16 18:00:00";

var daterange1 = dateRange.Split(';');

daterange1.Select(t => t.Split(',').Select(r => r.Replace(r, TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Parse(r), selectedTimeZone).ToString())));
```

each comma separated string contain startdate and enddate.

Comment: A good example for when LINQ is inappropriate

Comment: Show the comma separated string in your question and show the desired outcome.

Comment: Why do a `Replace` on `r` instead of just parsing, convert to utc, and tostring (or better yet keep it as a `DateTime`)?  Basically `r.Replace(r, whatever)` is the same as just `whatever`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I know something is wrong in that linq statement, better if you would have corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will do it - tested

```
var dates = "2016-02-15 17:30:00,2016-02-15 18:00:00,2016-02-16 17:30:00,2016-02-16 18:00:00";
DateTime[] utcDates = dates.Split(',').Select(d => DateTime.Parse(d)).Select(dt => dt.ToUniversalTime()).ToArray();

foreach (var d in utcDates)
{
       Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

@mxmlc pointed out that my answer is not exactly the answer. so, here is another variation that should answer this for sure. It contains comma-separated start/end and semicolon separated date sets

```
var dates = "2016-02-15 17:30:00,2016-02-15 18:00:00;2016-02-16 17:30:00,2016-02-16 18:00:00";

// prepare results
// Legend: se = start/end; sed = stard-end date
var utcDates = dates.Split(';').
               Select(se => se.Split(',')).
               Select(se => new DateTime[]{ 
                                  DateTime.Parse(se[0]).ToUniversalTime(), 
                                  DateTime.Parse(se[1]).ToUniversalTime()});

// print out results                
utcDates.Select(sed => string.Format("Start Date: {0}; End Date: {1}", sed[0], sed[1])).
         ToList().
         ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Anil says that he has a start and end date (comma separates the start and end date while semicolon separate the groups of start and end dates) and in your answer there are no semicolon occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
string daterange = "2016-02-15 17:30:00,2016-02-15 18:00:00;2016-02-16 17:30:00,2016-02-16 18:00:00";

var result = daterange.Split(';').Select(delegate(string strStartEndDates)
{
    string[] arrStartEndDates = strStartEndDates.Split(',');

    DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Parse(arrStartEndDates[0]);
    DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Parse(arrStartEndDates[1]);

    /*
        TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
        DateTime timeZoneStartDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dtStart, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
        DateTime timeZoneEndDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dtEnd, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
    */

    return new { Start = dtStart.ToUniversalTime(), End = dtEnd.ToUniversalTime() };

}).ToList<dynamic>();
```

Nothing special with it, but you can chose a TimeZone if needed (see commented lines). I've used dynamic to make it easier for me, but you can create a class.